# when I request rails server, how to access directive file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, directive

for example,
I have url "http://10.0.0.1:3000/image/a.jpg".
So I request rails server with url.

but rails server use url (ex. "protocol://ip/controller/action.").

how to directive access "http://10.0.0.1.:3000/image/a.jpg"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the `a.jpg` in `public` folder, so the Rails file path should be `<rails_root>/public/image/a.jpg`.

When you access the Rails app, `localhost:3000/image/a.jpg` should be loading your image.